# Why doesn't toggleClass work in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari

I have the following code:

```
$(".tglmenu").click(function(){
    $('.mobile_divinner').toggleClass('slideout');
    $(this).toggleClass('tglclose');
    $('.wrap').toggleClass('mainopen');
});
```

I've noticed that in Safari, the classes are not been added. 
Any ideas?

Comment: does the click event trigger?

Comment: Mobile Safari or desktop? I've certainly not encountered this issue before. I'd suggest checking the DOM to see if the click event is fired, the class is actually being applied and that CSS rules are specific enough.

Comment: I've tested it on both mobile and desktop (on a minimized window). I've put an alert to confirm that the click method is being triggered and only the toggleClass method is not working. Everything else lookes fine and it all works on the other browsers.